# $f$ is continuous and $f(c)=5$. Find some neighbourhood s.t. $f(x)\in[4,6]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am reviewing for exams and have come across a problem that seems easy but im unsure how the concepts tie together to give me an answer. The question is as follows:

> Suppose $f$ is continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(c)=5$. Prove there is some open neighbourhood $U$ of $c$, s.t. $f(x)\in[4,6] \forall x\in U$

I know by the definition of continuity about the point $c$, the neighbourhood $|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon,\delta>0$. Now this final implication allows me to expand:

$|f(x)-5|<\epsilon \iff 5-\epsilon<f(x)<5+\epsilon$

From here is it sufficient to fix $\epsilon=1$ to complete the proof? I don't quite understand how the concept on continuity fits into this question. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. Choose some $\delta$ that works for $\epsilon=1$, and then $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ is the required neighborhood.

Comment: how would I go about finding such a delta?

Comment: You can't find it, because you don't know anything about the function. But you know such $\delta$ exists because of continuity at $c$.

Comment: I see. So there is no explicit values of c and $\delta$ which forms $U$. The existence of $\delta$ when $\epsilon=1$ is possible since $f$ is continuous a $c$. What confuses me still is why does $f$ evaluated at points within this interval give us the desired mapping to $[4,6]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is continuous, so
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \text{ and } a \in \mathbb R , \exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that } |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon.$$

So choosing $\varepsilon = 1$ and $a=c$, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $$|x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)|  = |f(x) - 5|< 1.$$ That is, if $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ (an open neighbourhood of of $c$), then $f(x) \in (5 + 1, 5 - 1) \subseteq [4,6]$, as required. We don't know what $\delta$ actually *is*, but we know it exists. The question asks for the proof that there is *some* open neighbourhood, so this is sufficient.